# Does making a MySQL select/update more specific make it faster / give it better performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

In MySQL or SQL, does making a select or update query more specific make it faster?

What I mean is, is this query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET column = 'Hi Mom!' WHERE `id` = 123 AND `grouping_id` = 456 AND `other_column` = 0;
```

...faster than this query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET column = 'Hi Mom!' WHERE `id` = 123;
```

I've been ruining test queries on a large database and I can see that making the query more specific makes MySQL examine less rows. However It doesn't necessarily seem faster or less processor intensive. Any thoughts?

---

Note: Most columns I would use to narrow down the results, in this case `group_id` are either indexed or a Boolean.

Comment: Have you looked at the [execution plan](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9990/SQL-Tuning-Tutorial-Understanding-a-Database-Execu) to see for yourself ?

Comment: depends if you have primary keys, indexes and are using it, have you checked that on your tests ?

Comment: Provided `id` is the primary key, I'm guessing that's the only index the planner will use to find the row.  After it locates the row it will of course check to make sure the other conditions are true, but this would of course be quite fast since it's only looking at a single row.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend browsing through [this site](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) if you *really* want to know what's going on under the covers.

Comment: PhaDaPhunk No I hadn't gone as deep as the execution plan. Thank you I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the more specific your query the better but in terms of access time it still has to comb the index to find a given record. Smaller result sets just means there are less hits to return and thus you see a speed increase.

I often use EXPLAIN Queries to see exactly what is happening to a given query as it passes through the SQL Engine. MS SQL has a handy Query Diagnose feature.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `someCol` FROM someTable;
```

Comment: Thanks I'm going to run some more tests.